# Have we sent radio signals to exoplanets that may be habitable?

Tags: exoplanet, seti

I would like to know please whether or not we have sent radio signals to exoplanets that may be habitable.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : Yes

Long answer : Yes

We have actually sent radio signals to distant exoplanets that are thought to be capable of hosting (hopefully intelligent) life.

Some examples?

- [The radio signal directed at a world 12 light-years away included music and math lessons from Earth](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/interstellar-message-beamed-to-nearby-exoplanet/)
- [Are There Any Habitable Exoplanets That Can Hear Us?](https://www.wired.com/2015/07/habitable-exoplanets-can-hear-us/)

The second link only 'mentions' a planet that had been sent radio planet :

> Those waves, which are all electromagnetic like light, would have since traveled about 70 light years away from Earth. The newly confirmed Kepler 452b, at 1,400 light years away, will not be seeing 'I Love Lucy' for more than a millennium.

Hope this answers your question.